# AMS transfer from 0.9 to 0.10. What's the best way to achieve embed: ids option (return ids of relationship)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to run a project using new Active Model Serializer development (0.10rc3),

What I found from logs - possibility to embed ids of relationship has been removed.

In earlier versions of AMS it was possible to declare:

```
class CompanySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true
  attributes :id, :name

  has_many :employees
end
```

Right now it should be achieved using :include directive to serialization adapter, but it's not clear from documentation how to do it for a JSON adapter.

Could anybody advise, please?

Answer (score 0):

There is an ongoing discussion about adding a sideloading json adapter to AMS. There is also an ongoing discussion about building legacy adapters to ease the transition.

Comment: Thank you, would you suggest best workaround for now, or just stick at 0.9 version?